# How to strip a certain string from each the list items

Tags: list, python-3.x, loops, strip

I have `list` of file paths inside `C:\` stored in a list called `filepaths`, now i have to strip off `C:\` from all the `filepaths` while doing a for loop.

I'm not able to find a strip method while looping, as each element is coming as Type `list`. Please find my code below.

```
filepaths = ['C:\folder\file1.jpg','C:\file2.png','C:\file3.xls']
tobestriped = 'C:\'
for filepath in filepaths:
    newfilepath = filepath.strip(tobestriped)
    print(newfilepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to begin with, in `tobestriped` you'll get an error as `\'` will be escaped. You can use `tobestriped = 'C:\\'`.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/6165050) SO answer:

> A "raw string literal" is a slightly different syntax for a string
>   literal, in which a backslash, \, is taken as meaning "just a
>   backslash" (except when it comes right before a quote that would
>   otherwise terminate the literal) -- no "escape sequences" to represent
>   newlines, tabs, backspaces, form-feeds, and so on. In normal string
>   literals, each backslash must be doubled up to avoid being taken as
>   the start of an escape sequence.

Next, In your paths list `\f` will also be escaped. To get rid of this issue, make those strings raw strings:

```
filepaths = [r'C:\folder\file1.jpg', r'C:\file2.png', r'C:\file3.xls']
```

An you will have the desired result:

```
filepaths = [r'C:\folder\file1.jpg', r'C:\file2.png', r'C:\file3.xls']
tobestriped = 'C:\\'

for filepath in filepaths:
    newfilepath = filepath.strip(tobestriped)
    print(newfilepath)
```

Output:

```
folder\file1.jpg
file2.png
file3.xls
```

An alternative to your solution would be to take advantage of the fact that all your strings begin with `C:\` so you can do something like this:

```
print([x[3:] for x in filepaths])
```

Comment: i'm not able to do `newfilepath = filepath.strip(tobestriped)` as you have mentioned in your answer. i'm getting this error, `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: With the data you supplied, each of my solutions work. If your paths come themselves as lists, just to this before the for loop: `flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]`

Comment: Does it make any difference in the approach if i'm reading a csv file and making my `filepaths`  list ?

Comment: Let's not make this a never-ending story. Post all your relevant code and how your data actually looks like